# Monadic .NET Types

Tags: c#, .net, haskell, monads

[In a great series of posts](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/21/monads-part-one/) Eric Lippert outlines the so-called "Monad Pattern" for .NET types that kinda act like monads and implements return and bind for some of them.

As examples of monadic types he gives:

- `Nullable<T>`
- `Func<T>`
- `Lazy<T>`
- `Task<T>`
- `IEnumerable<T>`

I have two questions:

1. I get that `Nullable<T>` is kind of like `Maybe` in Haskell and binding several `Maybe`actions represents a set of operations that may fail at any point. I know the list monad (`IEnumerable<T>`) represents non-determinism. I even kinda understand what `Func` does as a monad (`Reader` monad).
   What are the monadic sematnics of `Lazy<T>` and `Task<T>`? What does it mean to bind them?
2. Does anyone have any more examples of types in .NET that kinda act like monads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The monadic bind function has the type:

```
Moand m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

so for `Task<T>` in C# you need a function which takes a `Task<A>` extracts the value and passes it to the binding function. If the task errors or is cancelled, the compound task should propagate the error or cancellation.

This is fairly straightforward using async:

```
public static async Task<B> SelectMany<A, B>(this Task<A> task, Func<A, Task<B>> bindFunc)
{
    var res = await task;
    return await bindFunc(res);
}
```

for `Lazy<T>` you should create a lazy value from a function which takes the result of another lazy computation:

```
public static Lazy<B> SelectMany<A, B>(this Lazy<A> lazy, Func<A, Lazy<B>> bindFunc)
{
    return new Lazy<B>(() => bindFunc(lazy.Value).Value);
}
```

I think that

```
return bindFunc(lazy.Value);
```

is invalid since it eagerly evaluates the value of `lazy` so you need to construct a new lazy which unwraps the value from the created lazy.

Comment: Thnaks, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Well, Haskell has laziness by default, so that wouldn't be very instructive in Haskell, but I can still show how to implement `Task`s as monads.  Here's how you would implement them in Haskell:

```
import Control.Concurrent.Async (async, wait)

newtype Task a = Task { fork :: IO (IO a) }

newTask :: IO a -> Task a
newTask io = Task $ do
    w <- async io
    return (wait w)

instance Monad Task where
    return a = Task $ return (return a)
    m >>= f  = newTask $ do
        aFut <- fork m
        a    <- aFut
        bFut <- fork (f a)
        bFut
```

It builds on the `async` library for convenience, but it doesn't have to.  All that the `async` function does is fork a thread to evaluate an action, returning a future.  I just define a small wrapper around that so that I can define a `Monad` instance.

Using this API, you can define your own `Task`s easily, just by supplying the action you want to fork when the `Task` is run:

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

test1 :: Task Int
test1 = newTask $ do
    threadDelay 1000000  -- Wait 1 second
    putStrLn "Hello,"
    return 1

test2 :: Task Int
test2 = newTask $ do
    threadDelay 1000000
    putStrLn " world!"
    return 2
```

Then you can combine `Task`s using `do` notation which creates a new deferred task ready to be run:

```
test3 :: Task Int
test3 = do
    n1 <- test1
    n2 <- test2
    return (n1 + n2)
```

Running `fork test3` will spawn the `Task` and return a future which you can invoke at any time to demand the result, blocking if necessary until done.

To show that it works, I'll do two simple test.  First, I'll fork `test3` without demanding its future just to make sure it spawns the composite thread correctly:

```
main = do
    fork test3
    getLine -- wait without demanding the future
```

This works correctly:

```
$ ./task
Hello,
 world!
<Enter>
$
```

Now we can test what happens when we demand the result:

```
main = do
    fut <- fork test3
    n   <- fut  -- block until 'test3' is done
    print n
```

... which also works:

```
$ ./task
Hello,
 world!
3
$
```

Comment: This wasn't quite what I was asking but while we're at it - binding tasks creates a resulting task which will preform all tasks concurrently and then produce some result?

Comment: I'm using the exact definition of `Task` on Eric Lippert's site: "Task<T> -- represents a T that is being computed asynchronously and will be available in the future, if it isn't already".  That is exactly what my `Task` type does.  The answer to your question is yes: binding tasks creates a new task which will perform all tasks concurrently when you run it.  Demanding the future from that composite task will wait for all subtasks to complete.

Comment: Grate, thanks, that answers my question on Task monadic semantics.